# Doxygen command line - error handling

Tags: doxygen

I use Doxygen in command line mode(via a batch file scheduled to run at certain time) for generating code documentation.

I supply it with a Doxyfile that has all the settings.
And it **overwrites** the previously generated documentation for same code.

My problem is, the input location name may change at some time.
So, in the log, doxygen shows that it cannot find ONE of the input locations.

What my aim is that the documentation should be generated/overwritten **ONLY IF** there is **NO ERROR**.

There are three possible solutions in my mind(in the order of decreasing convenience):

1. Interrupt docs generation in case of **ANY** error.
2. If its not possible to interrupt the docs generation, I can generate docs in some other place and then replace older ones using simple move command in batch file **IF** Doxygen has not thrown any errors. For this, I will somehow have to get hold of Doxygen errors in batch file runtime.
3. Save docs to different folder, save log to txt, scan txt in batch for errors(This, I can do but prefer avoiding)

So, is there any way I can get hold of this error while running Doxygen via batch file?

Comment: Why does your input location change? If you know why and how this changes then surely it would be easiest to update the doxygen configuration file with the new input location, rather than shifting through the output of doxygen or trying to interrupt it?

Comment: its does not actually change.
there are slight modifications to folder name...
e.g. abcv200 to abcv201 to indicate version change from 20.0 to 20.1

Comment: Then I think the best bet is to ensure that you update you doxygen configuration file with each release. I'm afraid I don't see why you think you need a more complex solution.

Comment: The reason is I have scheduled the batch to run on my server and shared the docs with my team. And I don't want to login to server and update the config file every time the folder name changes(which is quite often).

Comment: Ok. But what changes the folder name? The same process can be used to update your configuration file automatically.

Comment: In your doxygen config have doxygen output to some temporary directory, and have doxygen print all warnings to some file. Have a script call doxygen. Verify that doxygen's exit code is 0 and then check to see that the warning file's length is 0. If both are true, then copy the doxygen output to the release directory. The delete the temporary output directory.